# Spring MVC, parsing JSON without writing additional classes

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to re-write an app already written in PHP.

I want to pass a complex JSON string to the spring MVC controller (using AJAX post) so that it can save it in the database. I just need to extract few values from the JSON in the controller and hence would not like to create classes for the entire structure.

I just need the templateName and templateId from this JSON object. Is there a way I can extract some values from the JSON object.

I have written the below JSON to give an example:

```js
Sample JSON Structure:

{
  "templateName": "template1",
  "templateId": "t01",
  "templateObj": {
    "name" : "mytemplate",
    "values": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "drawings": [
      "circle": {
      "radius": 20,
      "color" : "#f3f3f3",
      "border": 1
      },
      "rectangle":{
        "width": 20,
        "height": 40,
        "color": "#f1f1f1"
      }
    ]
  }
}


Javascript Code:

$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: url,
 data: JSON.stringify(templateObj),
    ...
```

Java code -

@RestController
public class SaveChartConfigController {

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/saveChartConfig")
public @ResponseBody String processSaveChartConfig(@ModelAttribute JSONObject jsonObj) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can by doing this:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/saveChartConfig")
public @ResponseBody String processSaveChartConfig(@RequestBody String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Map<String, Object> jsonToMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);
    String templateName = (String) jsonToMap.get("templateName"); //here you get the parameters
    return templateName; //For example
}
```

Jackson Jars:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note: `import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;`

But, in your case, it will not work because your JSON it's not a valid JSON Object. If you fix this, then the code above it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response Raphael. I get an error saying "ObjectMapper cannot be resolved to a type". Would you kindly point me to the right libraries for fix this? I believe I need to add Jackson Jars. Also will this work for any JSON structure (any level of nesting)

Comment: Yes, it will. But if you need something inside another key, you have to get to do something like that: `Map<String,String> map = (Map) jsonToMap.get("templateName"); map.get("insideTemplateName")`. Well, see my edit for Jackson questions... I hope it helps...